# How to select bottom N rows based on sum of certain column and get the cumulative sum in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

If we have a table foo with quantity and price.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id INT, qty INT, price int);
INSERT INTO foo (id, qty, price) VALUES (1, 100, 10), (2, 120, 11), (3, 150, 12), (4, 170, 13), (5, 200, 14), (6, 210, 15);

+----+-----+-------+
| id | qty | price |
+----+-----+-------+
|  1 | 100 |    10 |
|  2 | 120 |    11 |
|  3 | 150 |    12 |
|  4 | 170 |    13 |
|  5 | 200 |    14 |
|  6 | 210 |    15 |
+----+-----+-------+
```

Here is the desired result given any number N:

```
if N = 210, derivedsum = 210*15 [id=6] 
if N = 300, derivedsum = 210*15 [id=6] + 90*14 [id=5]
if N = 430, derivedsum = 210*15 [id=6] + 200*14 [id=5] + 20*13 [id=4]
```

Explanation:

- When N = 210, it should pick price from last record
- When N = 300, it should pick price from last record[ id=6 ] for 210,
  and the remaining 90 [ 300 - 210 ] price should be picked with id = 5

Is it possible to achieve this in single query?

Comment: What's the relation between N and how many rows you want to use? Where does the 90 come from in row 5 in the second example, and 20 for row 4 in the third?

Comment: Shawn, I have updated the post by answering some of your questions.

Comment: I think you require logic that's not in SQL. Basically you traverse backwards in an array, each time evaluating remaining of N. A job for a programming language (pretty much any modern language will do). SQLite has no built-in language.  I would say "probably not doable"